# What is meant by "thank you" in quotes?

Tags: meaning-in-context, quotation-marks

In two different emails, I have seen *"thank you"* placed in quotes.

The first was a response to an email notice regarding an address change:

> “Thanks” for the e mail, I updated our system.

And the second was a response to a purchase order:

> "Thank you" for the order, we will ship (1) case on Thursday.

Why would someone use quotes in such a fashion?

Normally [I would assume sarcasm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scare_quotes), but it seems a bit rude (and therefore unlikely in a business email) sarcastically thanking someone for an order.

Comment: It looks like sarcasm to me... but maybe they just meant emphasis like *Thanks* (with asterisks).

Comment: Can you tell us if both times were from the same person?

Comment: @d'alar'cop Nope, two different people, which is why I didn't just think of it as a personal misuse of punctuation.

Comment: Is this actually a thing?  I've never seen it, and it's possible that you just happened to be emailed by the two random people in the world that don't really understand appropriate uses of quotation marks.  Has this been observed by others?  More data would help.

Comment: There are a lot of good explanations mentioned in this thread. One other possibility might be the authors thought *Thanks* or *Thank you* too casual for business correspondence. (Consider more formal phrasings like "We gratefully acknowledge your contribution," "We extend our gratitude to you," or "We appreciate your business with us.") Quotes may have been their way of showing they meant no disrespect if *Thanks* came across as unprofessional or too casual.

Comment: @dingo_dan You know, since it is a business context, that seems a much more likely explanation than any of the current, other answers. Go ahead and add it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From comments:

> There are a lot of good explanations mentioned in this thread. One other possibility might be the authors thought *Thanks* or *Thank you* too casual for business correspondence. (Consider more formal phrasings like "We gratefully acknowledge your contribution," "We extend our gratitude to you," or "We appreciate your business with us.") Quotes may have been their way of showing they meant no disrespect if *Thanks* came across as unprofessional or too casual.

Comment: Then why wouldn't they just have said the more formal version in the email? It would be interesting if the OP were to ask them what they meant by the quote marks!

Comment: I too would like to know the sources' meaning. In response to your question, I think the message's nature can be a reason. Both messages seem to serve more than one purpose: acknowledging, confirming (for the company's/client's records), and fulfilling a purchase or requested update to a database. Because these are effectively receipts (closer to memos than to more formal correspondences like notes of appreciation) choosing *looser* but more concise and to-the-point language makes sense to me.

Answer (score 4):

I can only surmise that they are trying to depict exact reported speech, imagining themselves actually saying "thank you" to you, rather than just thanking you in the email.

I have certainly seen this kind of usage out and about.

Here is a [similar example](http://www.unnecessaryquotes.com/2011/04/no-smoking.html), in which the quotation marks are clearly not sarcasm or scare quotes, nor a nonstandard expression, but probably exactly what the management would be prepared to say to you if you did not comply.

[image]

Comment: I'd say this was a poor attempt at a compromise between space available and grammatical clarity. Shows can't smoke, hence the scare quotes. Why not just write, 'No smoking is allowed on these premises'?

Comment: But then they might still have written *"No smoking" is allowed on these premises*. It's possible they meant it as a scare quote, but not everyone who writes a sign knows about scare quotes.

Comment: perhaps it was to avoid anyone making taking it another way, as Paul Shannon and H Vernon Watson did!

Comment: I had to look that up - but indeed!

Answer (score 2):

In this case it doesn't mean anything more than emphasis. Apparently the person is trying to draw your attention to the word *thanks.* He could have emboldened or italicized it, but I don't know why he didn't.

Comment: It's "wrong" in the sense that I don't think that there's a community of people who would normally use quotes as a means of emphasis - whereas old-time email/computer users `*do*` use asterisks.

Comment: @snori74 Given the context at hand, one can only think that the sender had nothing more than emphasis in mind. How accurate that is, we cannot say. I'd personally never use quotes the way they are used here.

Comment: I wouldn't use quotation marks that way, but **many** people do.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this was a clear example of the use of [scare quotes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scare_quotes).

I'd assume the use was unintentional unless proven otherwise, but I would point it out politely in a response.

Comment: I'd be tempted to point it out, but I'd try to stop myself as I think it would sound pedantic and condescending.